# How to center form elements with materialize classes

Tags: css, materialize

I have a form like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12" onSubmit={formSubmit}>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s10">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input name="username" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s10">
                    <input name="password" type="password" />
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s10">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <p>Don't have an account? <strong><a href="/register">Register</a></strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to horizontally center the form input fields within the .container `div` and left align the `h3` and submit `button` with those input fields but can't figure out how to do it using Materialize helpers and built-in grid classes. I've tried .center-align but as per the [docs](https://materializecss.com/helpers.html) its only for text. I'm missing something in how the grid system works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are using React or Angular because in HTML there is no `className` it's `class`, if true; it will be better to change `className` into `class` to make a working demo so people can help. I already have added MaterializeCDN to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit it

Comment: are you looking to center the whole form? or you want to center the elements inside the form however the form is centered or not?

Comment: btw, you forgot to change `className="container"` and `className="row"`

Comment: I want to center the whole form. but keep the submit button aligned-left to the username and password input fields - btw updated the col sizes to better demonstrate

Comment: The form as well as the inputs are currently centered! but the thing that makes them looks like they are not centered is because `inputs` have `class='s10'`, you can instead use `class='s12'`

Comment: Ok, I that looks better! what if I wanted the size of the form col to be s8? how can I get that to be in the center of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/) you can use the grid utility of [push/pull](https://materializecss.com/grid.html#grid-push) to center your `col`.

**Explanation:**

If you have `col s8`, then the remaining `columns` for this `row` is **4** so to center it there should be `col s2` before `col s8`.

Now, `push-s2` will acts as an empty `col s2` before `col s8` so it will be centered.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s8 push-s2" onSubmit={formSubmit}>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input name="username" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input name="password" type="password" />
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12">
                 <p>Don't have an account? <strong><a href="/register">Register</a></strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Disadvantages of this way**

You can't do this way with an odd `col` number (ie: `col s7`) because then the remaining `columns` for this `row` is **5** and there is no `col s2.5` neither `push-s2.5`.

**My Opinion**

Remove `<div class='row'>` from above `form` and remove  `class='col s12'` from inside the form, instead you can use `max-width` with `margin: 0 auto` to center the `form` then keep everything else as is, see below:

```css
.main-form {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .main-form {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="container">
        <form class="main-form" onSubmit={formSubmit}>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input name="username" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input name="password" type="password" />
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12">
                 <p>Don't have an account? <strong><a href="/register">Register</a></strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```